# Google sheet attendance report

Tags: google-sheets

So i made a unique barcode for every employee where upon scanning, it will register inside google sheets with their name and id number then it is recorded by timestamp. i made this using google form..

I wanted to have a summary that shoes the number of days an employee had their duty per month, I planned to do another response sheet every month. I have all set up but some of my colleagues scanned twice in a matter or few seconds.

My problem now is per day, some has 2 names on it, some are 4 names, because they scanned the same number of times..

Now my problem is when i Count lets say Person A, it is more than the expected per day. it should be one count per day but since Person A accidentally scanned twice, his name appears twice..

I hope I explained it in a way that you understand :) I only know basic in excel.

I did this because now that there is pandemic, we are only paid by the number of days we had our duty.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you also log the timestamp when the scan was performed? If so you could eliminate duplicates based on some threshold on the delta between two timestamps

Answer (score 1):

Carlo, this should be easy enough to address. However, we can't see your sheet. So it would be tough to suggest a formula that solves your issue.

If you'll share a sample sheet, being sure to set permissions to "Anyone with the link can edit," someone here will be able to help you.

That said, I can try to help on general principles.

Let's say your form sends the data to a sheet called "Form." And let's say the timestamp goes to Column A, and the worker's ID goes to Column B. In a new sheet (let's call it "FormProcessed", you could put this formula into A1 of the newly created sheet and it would produce a list that rules out duplicates in the same day. This assumes that you don't care about the exact *time* someone checked in, but only the *day*:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER({IFERROR(INT(Form!A:A),Form!A:A),Form!B:B},Form!B:B<>""))
```

In the same setup I described, if you DO need to keep the exact time (of the first check-in) without duplicates, this longer formula placed in the new sheet should accomplish that:

```
=ArrayFormula({Form!A1:B1;FILTER({Form!A2:A,Form!B2:B},Form!A2:A<>"",VLOOKUP(INT(Form!A2:A)&Form!B2:B,{INT(Form!A2:A)&Form!B2:B,ROW(Form!A2:A)},2,FALSE)=ROW(A2:A))})
```

In either case, you'd then just refer to the new FormProcessed sheet instead of your raw Form sheet in any other formulas you create to work with the data.

Hopefully, those ideas work or help steer you in the right direction. Beyond that, we'd have to have access to your sheet to give further help.